# Optimistic concurrency exception while insert data into database in dot net entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, insert

I am new in .Net entity framework. In that I am facing one issue while insert some data into database. 
For insert data, using below code,

```
 var emp =   employeeContext.Employees.Add (employee)                
            employeeContext.Entry(emp).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            employeeContext.SaveChanges();
```

The below error message is showing while executing the above code.

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.'
```

Please help me

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with `employeeContext.Entry(emp).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;`? First (by calling `Add`) you are telling EF to *insert* employee record, and then you are telling it to *update* it instead (which of course is failing since employee doesn't exist).

Comment: Actually I want to insert the employee details to database. For that, How I change this code?

Comment: It can't be said w/o [mcve]. Add `employeeContext.Database.Log = s => Console.WriteLine(s);` (or `Debug.WriteLine`) and see (tell us) what `INSERT` / `UPDATE` SQL commands are logged during the `SaveChanges` call.

Comment: I changed the code like employeeContext.Entry(emp).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;. Now the error changed. Now it showing "SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EmployeeId', table 'Study.dbo.test'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
". I checked the values. In that EmployeeId haas value (integer value). How to resolve this

Comment: issue is rsolved. Thank you for your suggetions.